# Where does OS X server store my project?

Tags: xcode, git, osx-server

my question is I downloaded and installed a OS X Server from AppStore to my Mavericks. Then I made a repository in it for my Xcode apps.

1. I want to know where the OS X server saves the project I commit from the XCode? The server shows a path something like https//XYZ%20ABC@server.local/git/TrialXCodeProj.git. But I haven't made any account in git. What exactly is this git and does it stores my code in git cloud or my local hard disk?
2. The client wants the code to be stored in his own machine where the server is installed. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope you understand it now.